# ListPopupWindow can not be clicked on Android 4.2, but works well in Android 7.0

Tags: android, popupwindow

I wrote a simple APP with Adroid Studio 3.0 (via basic activity template):

in the "content_main" layout, only an "EditText"

- Feature1: when I click the "EditText", IME will be shown and also a ListPopupWindow will be shown with a list of strings.
- Feature2: At this time, I can continue to input in the EditText while the ListPopupWindow is shown there.
- Feature3: And I can scroll the ListPopupWindow and click an item, then the item wil be shown in EditText and ListPopupWindow will be dismissed.

My problem is:

Running on Android 7.0, I can select one item in the ListPopupWindow.

But on Android 4.2, the items in ListPopupWindow can not be clicked.

My analysis:

- if I chage to: `listPopupWindow.setModal(true)`, Feature2 can not be implemented.

Following is the key source code:

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    EditText productName;
    ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
    String[] products={"Camera", "Laptop", "Watch","Smartphone", "Television"};

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
        productName.setText(products[position]);
        listPopupWindow.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        productName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_name);

        listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
                MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_item, products));

        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(productName);

        listPopupWindow.setModal(false);

        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(
                MainActivity.this);
        productName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listPopupWindow.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: set click listener before show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of normal `EditText` and there is no need to use `ListPopupWindow`, autocomplete will do your needed task as you want to show suggestions to a user while writing something. Here is the
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I do not need a pure enter-completion. I just need a series of similar items, including the exactly-matched one. And according to the input info, the list items will be updated. My problem is: it works well on Android 7 but cannot be selected on Android 4.2 :-(